# Oracle admin tool for mac os x

Tags: macos, database-administration

I'm looking for desktop admin tool similar to Navicat for Oracle in Mac os X. Navicat it's OK but it is quite buggy. Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [Oracle SQL Developer for Mac OS X platforms](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Insight Developer for Oracle](http://www.tncas.com).

Insight Developer is an lightweight solution for Oracle database development.